# Fetching database from MySQL to SQLite

Tags: mysql, ios, sqlite, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to complete an iPhone app. And for this i need to fetch a database from MySQL to SQLite. For this case i did use some code like bellow-

```
MCPConnection *theConnec;
MCPResult *theRes;
//initialize connection string vars
NSString *dbURL = @"XXXXXX";
NSString *userName = @"XXXXXX";
NSString *pass = @"XXXXXX";
//open connection to database
theConnec = [theConnec initToHost:dbURL withLogin:userName password:pass usingPort:3306];
//NSLog(@"The connection to database was successfull");
[theConnec selectDB:@"XXXXXX"];
//{
// NSLog(@"Database found");
//}
//else
//{
// NSLog(@"Database not found");
//}
theRes = [theConnec queryString:@"select * from seahawk_tag"];
//get the number of rows
NSInteger numberOfRows = [theRes numofRows];
NSLog(@"Query of MySQL Database %@", numberOfRows);
return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **) argv);
[theConnec release];
```

But this code does not work properly. Here also mention that i have used some framework like cocoa.framework, cocos2d, openGLES.framework, openAL.framework, APPKit.framework, MCPKit.framework, Quartzcore.framewrok . 
and finally i get an error msg that CIColer.h is missing.

freinds, if u know the solution or if u have another code then pls help  me

Comment: Coud you put code tag around code. It looks encrypted now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to poll a remote database, or how to pre-export?

Polling a remote database and importing data ***should*** be as simple as opening the socket to the remote db, executing the query, and closing again.